# send custom object in response when jwt authentication fails in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have created a ASP.NET WEB.API project with OWIN JWT Authentication. Is is working as expected, but what I want is to show custom validation message to use instead of default message if JWT authentication fails.
Right now it shows

```
{
"message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

This is my Validation Code.

```
public class OwinStartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpStatusCode statusCode;
        HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
           app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
               new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                   TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       ValidIssuer = "http://jwt.com",  
                       ValidAudience = "http://jwt.com",
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("jwt_key_asdf"))
                   }
               });
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e )
        {
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Failed") /////// Even tried this but it does not work.
            };
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```